# IIR (non linear phase) filters

Tags: filters, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response, finite-impulse-response

As you know, a nonlinear phase filter (in passband), distorts the frequency contents of passband region of signal. In general, Why do we use such filters in the case they cause distortion in the frequency contents of signals?

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18956/fir-vs-iir-complexity?s=6|27.5101

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32129/whats-the-advantage-of-adaptive-iir-filter-against-fir/35503#35503

Comment: also, in cases where you don't care about linear phase / constant group delay, you obviously don't benefit from linear phase / constant group delay. ("If a bike can't carry an elephant, unlike a truck, why do we still use bikes?" because we don't always have to transport elephants)

Comment: Thanks for your nice comments. Suppose we have a rectangular pulse (simply 0 for low state and 1 for high state) , which we added different noises and we want to extract its transient times. What type of filtering you propose?  I just know that we should use lowpass filter to cut out the noise in the higher frequencies. But IIR or FIR? I want to just simulate that in PC with different filters.

Comment: That depends. A lot in that problem says "I don't care about constant group delay" (and you're able to infer that in that case, you don't need constant group delay, so an IIR would be sufficient). But maybe your system has other constraints (input ranges, stability, latency constraints, complexity constraints, implementation on specific hardware)… So, it depends.

Comment: https://twitter.com/swiftonsecurity/status/1002403110151745536

Comment: My main concern: Our rectangular pulse transition (time domain) is not sharp; it takes a while to change from its low state to its high state (smooth change). As you know, this transition region contains many frequencies, and non-constant group delay distorts such frequencies. If I'm wrong please hint me. ?!

Comment: because we might not care so much about the phase response.  or maybe the non-linear phase is not all that great in the passband.  IIR filters can be easy to design from analog prototypes and IIR filters have much more *"selectivity"* per filter order than do FIR filters.

Comment: well, the question really is *in what context* and *for what purpose* are you filtering, detecting that edge. Much points to you not actually *needing* a classical linear filter, no matter IIR or FIR, but something like timing recovery. What you really need isn't understandable from what you write – we're missing "the bigger picture". The fact that you're already observing a non-ideal edge points to you probably wanting something that more resembles a matched filter or correlator than a general low-pass filter, for example. In fact, I'm pretty sure LPF is not the answer to your question alone

Comment: It is an optical system which gives us a pulse in 360 degree; we do not know the pulse length (it could be variable, dependent on the situtation of the system, i.e. rotation of system). I have to determine the corresponding degree of each transient (for example, I have to claim that our pulse starts at 60 degree and ends at 180 degree). I have to extract transients. I have decided to apply a filtering; then apply a detection criteria (such as simple thresholding or derivative of pulse then applying thresholding on its derivative). Thanks in advance.